# Square image capture with react native

Tags: react-native, camera, image-capture

I want to customize the default camera to somewhat like instagram camera. How can I ensure that the images captured by my application is always in square shape? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this package: https://github.com/wix/react-native-camera-kit which provides cropping to specified aspect ratio, so you can use 1:1 to get a square.